# Setting up jenkins pipeline to deploy on local kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, minikube

I've been trying to setup a jenkins pipeline so that it deploys a docker image on local kubernetes cluster.

task overview :

- using jenkins server, connecting to SCM to get the code [completed]
- deploy that on local kubernetes setup (yaml files are available on repo)

I tried installing jenkins msi file and installed necessary plugins but, I have no idea about how things work together. I tried running jenkins installed on local disk and also on kubernetes but, I don't know how to complete this task. (I'm using windows server 2022)

The thing is there are so much implementation with only few details and mainly focusing on actual kubernetes services provided by Cloud service providers. In my last attempt, I tried installing jenkins it gets code from github but when it tries to deploy, it gets authentication error. I don't want to just resolve this issue, I need a clear overview of how things work and also if you guys could recommend me some texts or documents that are beginner friendly on how to setup jenkins and to work with local kubernetes cluster.

Comment: How would you deploy things outside of Jenkins?  Can use use the same `sh 'kubectl apply ...'` or `sh 'helm upgrade --install ...'` commands in a Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think that Jenkins would be you running the `kubectl apply` command. If you do it, you can add this command into the pipeline but you can also use a plugin so Jenkins can connect to the cluster as it was a cloud provider.

To do it by adding the command into the pipeline, you have to use an image with kubectl installed with the proper `kubeconfig.yaml` file so it can connect to the cluster.

Comment: so, let's say I'm running jenkins server on a localhost. I have to setup a service account for jenkins and deploy jenkins agent in one of the worker nodes right ?